# How to automate the creation of bundles for an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

My iOS app uses data that is packaged by theme into theme bundles. For example `theme_math.bundle`, `theme_history.bundle`, etc. A theme bundle contains a .sqlite file and images. The idea would be that those bundles can be downloaded when necessary by the app (theme_x.bundle.zip).
There are hundreds of themes that are stored in a database, and I'd like to automate the process of creating a bundle for every theme with the appropriate name.

- Is this approach fine to deliver application content to an iOS app?
- If using bundles is fine, how can I automate that process?

Comment: If you like my answer it would be great if you would "accept it" - we both get points when you do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would appear to be a fine idea. You can automate this by creating a shell program file, or use some other scripting language (python, ruby, etc).

A bundle is really just a folder that gets special treatment. It can have an icon when viewed in the Finder, etc. So your high level program will create a bundle (mkdir Name.bundle), then copy whatever resources you want into that directory - Name.bundle. When you're done zip the bundle up, and put it where it can be downloaded.

Bundles often have a plist inside with special flags set (as an executable on OSX does), but don't think you need this.

Its possible that you may need to set some special bits on the bundle for iOS to recognize it - I really don't know for sure. If so see [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2009687/96716)

Comment: Ha great, I thought I would have to create some project in Xcode for it to work. I'll try this. Thanks!