# Show folder as file on mac

Tags: macos, directory

Mac Finder is able to show some folders as plain files.
For example, it can show folders with .app and .xcodeproj extensions as files.

I am developing an application which stores files in so-called projects. A project is a folder with some files and app-specific extension.

What should I do to force Finder to show projects of my app as files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009687/make-mac-package-bundle-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The concept is know as "file package" or ["document package"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW3) (often also referred to with the slightly wrong term "bundle").

An application can declare in its Info.plist a document type and set the `LSTypeIsPackage` key to `true`. In the Xcode UI there is a checkbox for this called "Document is distributed as a bundle".

[image]

When the app is installed on a Mac the Finder will display any directory with the extension of the document type as a file.

Comment: Thanks. However, I use Qt, and comment by lupatus seems to be what I've looked for.